# Частое использование статики при ведении Лога С#

Tags: c#, производительность, .net-core

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой **логгирования сообщений** у чат бота для Twitch.tv(видео платформа для стримминга).

Итак, вкратце, как работает бот: есть статический метод `Process` который ждет получения сообщение от сервера и создает задачу вызова асинхронного обработчика выбора канала, для которого предназначено сообщение, добавляет в очередь, `Task.Run(() => SwitchMessage(buf)))`. Внутри него для нужного экземпляра Channel вызывается статический `Handler(message)`. Для общего понимания*

Теперь к проблеме. Написал я значит логгер:

```
internal static class Logger
{
    static readonly int timeHours = 24; 
    static string path = $"./logs/log{DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(':','.')}.txt";
    static FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);
    static Timer timerLogFile = new Timer(CreateNewLogFile, null, timeHours * 60 * 60000, timeHours * 60 * 60000);

    public static void Write(string message)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            return;
        if(stream == null)
            stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);
        var buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + message + "\n");
        stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        stream.Flush();
    }
    static void CreateNewLogFile(object obj)
    {
        path = $"./logs/log{DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(':', '.')}.txt";
        stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append);
    }
}

private static void Process()
{
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            string s = ircClient.ReadMessage();
            if (s != null)
                Task.Run(() => SwitchMessage(s));

            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            ShowLineMessage(ex.Message);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
}

private static void SwitchMessage(string data)
{
    try
    {
        Message currentMessage = new Message(data);

        if(ViewChannel != null && currentMessage.Channel == ViewChannel.Name && currentMessage.Msg != null)
            ShowLineMessage(currentMessage.UserName + ": " + currentMessage.Msg);
        else if(!currentMessage.Success)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            ShowLineMessage(data);
            Console.ResetColor();
            lock (ErrorListMessages)
            {
                if (ErrorListMessages.Count > 50)
                    ErrorListMessages.Clear();
                    ErrorListMessages.Add(currentMessage);
                }
                return;
            }
            else if (currentMessage.UserName == "moobot" || currentMessage.UserName == "nightbot")
                return;

            if (currentMessage.Channel != null && Channels.ContainsKey(currentMessage.Channel))
            {
                Channels[currentMessage.Channel].Handler(currentMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                Channels.First().Value?.Handler(currentMessage);
            }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        ShowLineMessage(ex.Source + " " + ex.Message + " " + ex.Data);
        Console.ResetColor();
        return;
    }
}

private void Handler(Message msg)
{
    //...
    SendMessage(message);
    ShowLineMessage(message); 
};
```

И тут начались проблемы.
Заменил выводы в консоль `Console.WriteLine(...)` на некоторый метод:

```
public static void ShowLineMessage(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Logger.Write(message);
}
```

Это привело к тому, что при большем потоке сообщений, стал происходить дубляж сообщений, от 2 до 6 повторов в консоль и соответственно лог. Не могу понять с чем это связано...

P.S `ShowLineMessage` может вызываться одновременно скажем в 100 обработчиках сообщений(и это вполне реально). Могут ли возникать проблемы у ОС с частым вызовом статического метода `ShowLineMessage()`? Посоветуйте, как быть? Критика и совету к коду приветствуются! Спасибо!

Comment: После того, как разберетесь с ошибкой, выбрасывайте свой код и подключайте готовый логгер.

Comment: @andreycha например? под Net core

Comment: "Переходник" для [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging), например.

Comment: log4net пишет, что совместим с .NET Standard 1.3: https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/

Comment: Ну и в самом .NET Core есть стандартные провайдеры, для той же консоли, например. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело не в статичности статического метода `ShowLineMessage()`, а в использовании не потоко-безопасного объекта `FileStream` из разных потоков.

Внизу там про thread-safety:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx

Накапливайте сообщения в каком-нибудь Concurrent контейнере, и когда накопится скажем 1000 штук - подставляйте другой контейнер, а из накопленого - пишите.

И еще, откуда берется переменная `message` внутри метода `Handler`?

Comment: С записью в файл согласен, надо переделывать, но не в этом дело. Даже если в ShowLineMessage() оставить только Console.WriteLine(...). Тоже идет сбой, только с выводом сообщений в консоль. Раньше когда я просто вызывал Console.WriteLine() без инкапсуляции его в метод, все было нормально при любой нагрузке

Comment: @Xambey откуда берется переменная `message` внутри метода `Handler`?

Comment: Не суть, это отдельный класс-парсер сообщений, определяет Тип сообщения и данные. Проблема только в выводе лога.

Comment: @Xambey а может суть

Comment: нет, я уверен:) Скажите, а может мне лучше сделать в write() что-то вроде. Проверяем дескриптор файла, закрыт ли он. Ждем пока он будет закрыт. Создаем новый поток в using с открытием файла. Записываем. Поток закрывается. ? Во избежании потерь данных, если клиент навернется и потеряется контейнер, чтобы точно знать, когда и где.

Comment: @Xambey Вы таким образом сериализуете Ваши параллельные потоки, и вся параллельность - коту под хвост.

Comment: хм... наверное вы правы. Помечу ваш ответ, как 'ответ' через денек - два' если не будет вариантов лучше, спасибо!

Comment: сделал, как вы посоветовали, все круто, спасибо еще раз! Ставлю лойс)